# Running a Sub Query in a Mysql Statment

Tags: mysql

I got the following query but it is not working. Any help appreciated.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT * FROM Names WHERE suffix='1' AND word!='$main_suffix' ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 15)

     ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 3");
```

Comment: "not working" **HOW**? wrong results? no results? crashes your server? kicks your dog?

Comment: correction, not running.

Comment: so have the db tell you WHY it's not running. `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 1):

All subselects need an alias:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT * FROM Names 
       WHERE suffix='1' AND word!='$main_suffix' 
       ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 15) 
     ) YourAliasName
     ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 3");
```

Also, don't use `mysql_query`, but use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the alias  eg:as t at the end of subselect

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 
                (SELECT * 
                FROM Names 
                WHERE suffix='1' 
                AND word!='$main_suffix' 
                ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 15) as t
            ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 3");
```